# How to use TimedTextSource to view (srt) subtitle on MediaElement

Tags: c#, video, uwp, mediaelement, subtitle

I know that it is possible to view external subtitles with `MediaElement` but I do not get it that how. Can anybody explain me how to connect subtitles with `MediaElement`.

This is only clue I know so far. But how to tell `MediaElement` to use this?

```
    TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///TheVideoTitle.srt"), "en");
```

I found lot of information about this from Microsoft website:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.timedtextsource (Editied www url. By accident I pasted wrong one)
but they do not have any clear examples.

UPDATE

I created the following code. It starts to play video but still subtitle is missing. What's the problem. MediaElement has been created in XAML like this:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="MyVideoPlayer" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

This code still not work:

```
                        //Get MediaPlayerElement
                        MediaPlayerElement VideoPlayer = 'THE MEDIAPLAYER ELEMENT IN XAML';
                        //Get video file StorageFile
                        StorageFile VideoStorageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(GetMultimediaPlayer(ID).LocalVideoInformation.TitleFilePathOnStorage);
                        //Create MediaSource using VideoStorageFile as source
                        MediaSource VideoMediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(VideoStorageFile);
                        //Create subtitle Uri
                        Uri SubtitleUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///TheTestSubtitle.srt");
                        //Set SubtitleUri as source of TimedTextSource
                        TimedTextSource SubtitleTimedTextSource = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(SubtitleUri);
                        //Add TimedTextSource (SubtitleTimedTextSource) to MediaSource (VideoMediaSource)
                        VideoMediaSource.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(SubtitleTimedTextSource);
                        //Set MediaPlayerElement (VideoPlayer) source
                        VideoPlayer.Source = VideoMediaSource;
                        //Play
                        VideoPlayer.MediaPlayer.Play();
```

OK...Tried to copy from example code in GibHub but still the following code not work. In a void `Tts-Resolved` `args.Error` occur. (The system cannot find the file specifield.) Wondering what is the problem: All srt files etc. are exactly in same folders than in example app.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private Dictionary<TimedTextSource, Uri> ttsMap = new Dictionary<TimedTextSource, Uri>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("https://mediaplatstorage1.blob.core.windows.net/windows-universal-samples-media/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary.mp4"));

        var ttsEnUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/ElephantsDream-Clip-SRT_en.srt");
        var ttsEn = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(ttsEnUri);
        ttsMap[ttsEn] = ttsEnUri;

        var ttsPtUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/ElephantsDream-Clip-SRT_pt.srt");
        var ttsPt = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(ttsPtUri);
        ttsMap[ttsPt] = ttsPtUri;

        var ttsSvUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Media/ElephantsDream-Clip-SRT_sv.srt");
        var ttsSv = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(ttsSvUri);
        ttsMap[ttsSv] = ttsSvUri;

        ttsEn.Resolved += Tts_Resolved;
        ttsPt.Resolved += Tts_Resolved;
        ttsSv.Resolved += Tts_Resolved;

        source.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(ttsEn);
        source.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(ttsPt);
        source.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(ttsSv);

        var playbackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(source);

        playbackItem.TimedMetadataTracksChanged += (item, args) =>
        {
            playbackItem.TimedMetadataTracks.SetPresentationMode(0, TimedMetadataTrackPresentationMode.PlatformPresented);
        };

        mediaPlayerElement.Source = playbackItem;
    }

    private void Tts_Resolved(TimedTextSource sender, TimedTextSourceResolveResultEventArgs args)
    {
        var ttsUri = ttsMap[sender];
        if (args.Error != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var ttsUriString = ttsUri.AbsoluteUri;
        if (ttsUriString.Contains("_en"))
            args.Tracks[0].Label = "English";
        else if (ttsUriString.Contains("_pt"))
            args.Tracks[0].Label = "Portuguese";
        else if (ttsUriString.Contains("_sv"))
            args.Tracks[0].Label = "Swedish";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the timed text source to [`ExternalTimedTextSources`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.externaltimedtextsources#Windows_Media_Core_MediaSource_ExternalTimedTextSources) collection of the [`MediaSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource):

```
var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(mediaUri);
var timedTextSource = TimedTextSource.CreateFromUri(timedTextUri);
source.ExternalTimedTextSources.Add(timedTextSource);
```

For full working example see [this Windows Universal sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/e13cf5dca497ad661706d150a154830666913be4/Samples/VideoPlayback/cs/Scenario4_DisplayingOutOfBandClosedCaptions.xaml.cs).